# GIF files are not uploading in php script

Tags: php, image, file-upload, gif, ini

I'm trying to upload GIF files to my website, but for some reason its not uploading...by default does php allow it or we have to modify .ini file?

Basically in the console of inspect element in chrome its saying file not found error 404...  but when uploading the GIF, I get no upload related errors.

here is a snippet of the form tag:

```
<form id="add_element_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

All other image types jpg,png,jpeg get uploaded just fine, just not GIF files..

Comment: We need to see the php file that receives the uploads.

Comment: Check you PHP code, you most likely have some PHP code that is checking for filetype.  It is also possible that you have some javascript somewhere filtering out non jpg,png file types.

Answer (score 2):

Check your php.ini file and **phpinfo()** what will return and if they are equal then Check wheather you have more than one php.ini file.

Comment: How is this an answer?

Comment: Apparently, I was changing the wrong ini file and when PHP-FPM is used the ini file is the one inside the php-fpm directory.